# How can I draw a vertical line upon the horizontal lines in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-coder

I want to draw a vertical line in Matlab upon the concurrent horizontal lines and show the coordinates where the vertical line intersects the horizontal lines.I give a figure here, I want to write a code so that it draws a line first and show the co-ordinates on the intersection point automatically.

[image: Demo:]

Comment: Please mention what you have so far. The equations of the horizontal lines? Where do you want to draw the vertical line? An infinite number of solutions exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
L1 =  [0.7290    0.2163
    0.2026    0.9763] ; % line 1 coordinates 
L2 =   [0.5932    0.9677
    0.3044    0.8960] ;  % line 2 coordinates 

figure(1)
hold on
plot(L1(1,:),L1(2,:),'r')
plot(L2(1,:),L2(2,:),'b')
%% Get intersection
P = InterX(L1,L2) ;
%
plot(P(1),P(2),'*r')
%% Show points
text(P(1),P(2),num2str(P)) ;
```

Download function InterX from the link: 
https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22441-curve-intersections?focused=5165138&tab=function

Comment: Thanks for u r ans. But i want to do it on an image, which has some concurrent horizontal lines.

Comment: Yes..it can be done....do you have coordinates for those horizontal lines?

Comment: Bro i get those lines  after applying hough transform. so can i take it from hough transform ? Basically, now i want to apply a algorithm so that a vertical line flows from left to right and mark the intersection point when it intersects with the image horizontal lines.It also great for me if it shows the co-ordinates on the intersection point.